# Positive values of set derived from metric space

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have $(M, d)$ a metric space with $d$ the metric defined on $M$. We define the mapping $g : M \to M$ such that $d(g(u), g(v)) < d(u, v)$ for all $u, v \in X$ such that $u \neq v$. Now let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be the set containing the distances $d(u, g(u))$ for $u \in X$.

How might we show that $E$ has a nonnegative least element $\ell$? My intuition (largely gathered by drawing a sample diagram and examining some examples) is that it does, but I am struggling to construct anything resembling a concrete argument. A consequence of this also seems to be the fact that the set of elements $u \in X$ satisfying $d(u, g(u)) > (n\ell + 1)/n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ is open, but this is probably false - I only thought about it while considering constructions for the proof.

Comment: Do you consider $0$ positive?

Comment: Apologies, have edited to indicate nonnegativity instead of strict positivity.

Answer (score 0):

Counter-example: There is a unique $c>0$ such that $e^{-c}=c$. Let $E=\mathbb R \setminus \{-c,c\}$ and  $g(x)=e^{-|x|}$. Here,  the infimum is $0$ which is not attained.

Here is much better example which shows that $E$ can even be complete: Let $E=[0,\infty)$ and $g(x)=x+e^{-x}$. Use Mean Value Theorem to show that the hypothesis is satisfied. The infimum is again $0$ and it is never attained.

Comment: Apologies, I have recently edited the question; the infimum must be nonnegative.

Comment: In my example the infimum is $0$, hence non-negative but it is not attained at any point.

Comment: The map $g$ is not a map from $(c, \infty) \to (c, \infty)$: you can choose sufficiently large $x$ so that $e^{-x} < c.$

Comment: @ckefa Thank you for the correction. I have modified my example.